# Best way to extrude Isosceles triangle from edge

Tags: modeling, extrude

So I'm trying to figure out how to replicate this (picture attached). It seems pretty simple in concept, but I can't figure out how they did it. I have assumed it is based on some sort on extrusion from edge to tri, but I haven't figured out how that works. Does anyone have a clue?

[image: tail mesh constructed from tris obj mode]

[image: tail mesh constructed from tris edit mode]

Comment: It would be a better question if you created a simplified (minified) example, e.g. where you want to create/extrude (whatever you want to do) 3 triangles or so.

Answer (score 0):

### For 1 edge

Since you're asking about a single triangle… Select the edge, Create a custom orientation from it:

[image]

now <kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, <kbd>⬆ Shift</kbd><kbd>Y</kbd> to lock $y$ axis (defined a moment ago by using the edge), <kbd>M</kbd> to merge and either <kbd>A</kbd> or <kbd>B</kbd>:

[image]

### For multiple edges

You could use Goemetry Nodes to find a [perpendicular vector](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/278127/60486), then maybe rotate randomly and finally merge by distance:

[image]

[image]